# Invoking hook_custom_tokens and hook_custom_tokenValues in Joomla

Tags: joomla, hooks, tokens

I have tried, in vain, to invoke hook_civicrm_tokens and hook_civicrm_tokenValues in a Joomla instance in order to add custom tokens (to be specific: relationship information).

I created a Joomla plugin to allow this, as this seems to be the recommended way to implement hooks in Joomla, to no avail.  I have been unable to discover how the mail form gets its list of tokens in case I need to prefix the call names with that module, e.g. Mailing_civicrm_tokens.  I've looked at:

[Create Your Own Tokens for Fun and Profit](https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-fun-and-profit)
but it hasn't helped.  There is even a reference there to it [not working in Joomla](https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-fun-and-profit#comment-6929) that no one has answered the question.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's info about using CiviCRM hooks in Joomla:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Example+Joomla+Plugin+for+implementing+hooks

But why create a Joomla plugin if you can also use the hooks in a CiviCRM extension?
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension

The advantages of using a CiviCRM extension over a joomla extension:

- Works on all CMS'es
- Much more knowledge available in CiviCRM community

The only advantage of Joomla plugins I see would be if you would need to combine CiviCRM functionality with Joomla functionality.

Comment: is right -- there's really no need to build a Joomla plugin instead of a native CiviCRM extension. That said, either model should work. Try providing some sample code so we can see what you may have done wrong.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I also tried building a native CiviCRM extension as per the links provided above, but with thesame result - nothing. I don't need a form, I am simply trying to add hooks to add custom tokens in mailings.  There isn't space to provide code samples in a comment, but I am probably failing to provide the right class names etc. and have probably misunderstood the instructions somewhere. In the end, I followed the instructions in http://en.flossmanuals.net/civicrm-developer-guide/hooks/ to create a file for the hooks I am trying to add, and this seems to be working.

Comment: This appears to have stopped working with Joomla and CiviCRM 4.7.16.  I've tried debugging CiviCRM 4.7.20 and the joomla_civicrm_tokens and joomla_civicrm_tokenValues never appear to be being called.  Introducing an error to civicrmHooks.php doesn't cause CiviCRM to fail, so I suspect that civicrmHooks.php is no longer called.  Any comments?